# Picture changes depending value MySQL twig

Tags: mysql, twig

I am using DataTabales in a Twig file.

In the table there is a delete, edit and show button.
The delete and edit buttons are working with the code I wrote.

Now I am trying to get the show button working. 
Show is a green dot(picture) if the value in the MySQL table is 1.
Show is a red dot if the value in the MYSQL table is 0. The fieldname in the table is show.

I am trying:

```
<a href="show/"><{%if {{record.data.show=[0]}}img src="link : img     
src="otherlink" %} class="edit" align="right"></a>
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if record.XX == "0" %}
    <td><a href="/{{record.id}}"><img src="" class="">.</a></td>
{% elseif record.XX == "1" %}
    <td><a href="" class=""></a></td>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I made this, and it works... Just can't answer/accept my own question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax all mixed up.
 Either you use the shorthand expression

```
<img src="{{ var ? 'source.jpg' : 'other_source.jpg'}}" />
```

Or use a full `{% if %} {% endif %}`

```
<img src="{% if var %}source.jpg{% else %}other_source.jpg{% endif %}" />
```